# PHP/SQL - Password and Email security (theory)

Tags: php, sql, security, email, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to encode passwords in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391613/best-way-to-encode-passwords-in-php)

I've been reading a lot of things about password and email hashing and I am not quiet sure I figure out what is the best method. It's clear that md5 and SHA are outdated and pretty useless but when it comes to all the crypt's, mcrypt_encrypt, hash(), etc.:

- which one is an effective way of secure PASSWORDS AND EMAILS nowadays?;(maybe A BEST way?)
- can I use the same method for both?;

Really appreciated if someone could give me some advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this blog. It as ***good*** information about password hashing.

http://blog.ircmaxell.com/search/label/Password-Hashing

The author also has a password hashing library, which only uses quality, vetted algorithms.

That note aside, you should use bcrypt, or PBKDF2 for password hashing.

As for email encryption, PGP/GPG is your best bet for cross compatible/supported email encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this question [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) and this one [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php).

Both questions have more than 170 upvotes.