# Same hashing algorithm in Java and PHP gives different results

Tags: java, php, algorithm, encryption

I am integrating the same login functionality using same database on java and php platforms but having some problem in password algorithms.

Here is my java code:-

```
public static String encryptPassword(String strToEncrypt,String saltToEncrypt)      
{
    String encryptedString = "";
    String stringToEncrypt = "";
    byte[] encodedValue;

    stringToEncrypt = strToEncrypt + saltToEncrypt;

    encodedValue = Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.sha256(stringToEncrypt
            .getBytes()));
    encryptedString = new String(encodedValue);

    return encryptedString;
}
```

Here is my PHP code:-

```
  function  encryptPassword($strToEncrypt, $saltToEncrypt) 
  {
    $stringToEncrypt = $strToEncrypt.$saltToEncrypt;

    $encodedValue = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $stringToEncrypt));

    return $encodedValue;
 }
```

Ideally, both of these functions should generate the same encrypted string but these are giving different results.
What is wrong with my code? Please advise.

Comment: Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391613/best-way-to-encode-passwords-in-php), you're question has been answered

Comment: No it hasn't, that question is totally unrelated to this one.

Comment: show us the result

Comment: 2 things: `DigestUtils.sha256(stringToEncrypt.getBytes())` might produce a different result than `DigestUtils.sha256(stringToEncrypt)` due to endianess and PHP `hash` returns a hex string and not raw bytes. To get raw bytes from PHP pass a 3rd argument `hash('sha256', $stringToEncrypt, true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the SHA-256 functions do not use the same format for the return value. The `hash` function in PHP returns a hex string by default, but you can choose to output the raw string using the `RAW_OUTPUT` parameter (reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)) :

```
$encodedValue = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $stringToEncrypt, TRUE));
```

Alternatively, you may change the Java side and use a method named [`sha256Hex`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.8/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex(java.lang.String)) in Apache Commons Codec which takes a `String` and returns the hash in hexadecimal :

```
// You don't need the getBytes here
encodedValue = Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.sha256Hex(stringToEncrypt));
```

Comment: @CoffeNinja Thank you so much. It worked perfectly and that is the exact answer I was looking for. Many Thanks.

Comment: @pankajsharma glad to help.