# exporting username and password from form data to textfile using php

Tags: php, file, text

when user submit the form need to export form data to text file.exporting username ,password and email from form data to text file for forgot password.

Comment: I looked on your website to find any freelance clients you have so I could tell them you store plain passwords. Sadly I couldn't find any of your clients to tell. Just stop doing it, or go to jail.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you SURE you just want to write username and passwords to a file? This can be a huge security hole if you don't properly protect and encode this file.
See also this stackoverflow question on **[how to store passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retriev)** (plus many similar questions on stackoverflow, use search box above).

That said, in it's simplest form you could just store the username plus the (encrypted) password as a line in the password file, seperated by some character that cannot occur in the username. For example, the file could look like:

```
adam:fsSDFf34afdfgf43
bob:Djz3fdsDF67FSjFG
```

In PHP5 you can use [file_put_contents()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead of the standard fopen(), fwrite(), fclose() calls.