# Set database 'user' table for password recovery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, password-recovery

I have a question. I'm implementing a password recovery, then I thought: "What if a 'stranger' makes an unauthorized password recovery, changing someone's else password?"
So, my first decision is: I'll set two fields in the 'user' table, called 'password' and 'temp_password'. If the real user asks for a password recovery, the new random password will be stored in 'temp_password' and an e-mail will be sent. In this way, a spiteful user won't change anyone else password and the e-mail owner can deny the password change attempt. Is that right? Thank you in advance for your help.
Greetings

Comment: Yep. That's a good approach. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763719/php-password-recovery

Comment: Why not just generate the random password and replace the password when the user confirms via email? That way you don't need two fields, you just need the password field alone.

Comment: Also, you generally want passwords to have history (ie, to be able to disallow previously used passwords for that user), which means you often want a separate _table_ for passwords... at which point old passwords don't go away anyways.

Comment: You should not generate or email a new password - only a temporary token that will allow the user to reset their password themselves. You can email this with the knowledge that if anyone finds it at a later date it won't be useable. Once they follow the link they will be able to update the password - this will protect against anyone else resetting the password of another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you normalize this by storing the temp password in a separate table from your `user` table.  Each user will most likely have multiple password recovery attempts during their lifetime and you'll want to store a record of each of those attempts for posterity.

If you keep the field in the `user` table, each subsequent request after the first password recovery request will override the previous one.

Make sure you have a column in this new table that indicates which request is currently active and have server side / database scripts that ensure only one row per user ID can have an active flag.

Comment: +1 This approach is easily to expire the validity of the temporary password .

Comment: Right, I didn't think about that. I'll use another table! Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't really be storing a password - just a temporary reset token. This does not need to be a separate table as the reset via email can use the same value of multiple requests are sent in the same period.

Comment: @SilverlightFox You could store a token, but you definitely should have a separate table to track reset requests

Comment: I can't see why you'd need it - why would you have multiple password resets for the same user? Concurrent ones can use the same token.

Comment: @SilverlightFox You would only have one active one at any one time.  But for security purposes, you should keep a list of all past requests.  If an account has been hit with 200 reset requests in a day's time, there should be a flag that is set off

Comment: Agreed but that would be a separate table for auditing. The actual reset mechanism does not need to get involved with that - it can use the current token to determine whether the token is valid or not.