# How do you protect API keys and 3rd party site credentials (LAMP)?

Tags: php, mysql, api, credentials, api-key

I'm creating a site which will make use of ID's, Passwords, and API Keys to other 3rd party sites - for the server to access information accordingly.  For the purpose of this conversation, let's assume it is for a payment gateway - meaning exposure of this information that is stored in the DB could mean a malicious user could withdraw cash from the account whose credentials were leaked.

Unfortunately this isn't like a password / hashing situation, because the user does not input the credentials every time - they input it *once* and it is then saved on the server for future use by the application.

The only reasonable method that I can come up with (this will be a MySQL/PHP application), is to encrypt the credentials via a hardcoded "password" in the PHP application.  The only benefit here is that if the malicious user/hacker gains access to the database, but not the PHP code, they still have nothing.  That said, this seems pointless to me because I think we can reasonably assume that a hacker will get everything if they get one or the other - right?

If the community decides upon some good solutions, it would be nice to gather other sources to examples/tutorials/more in depth information so that this can be implemented in the future for everyone.

I was surprised I did not see this question with any good answers on stack already.  I did find this one, but in my case this doesn't really apply: [How should I ethically approach user password storage for later plaintext retrieval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie)

Thanks all.

Comment: Your bounty is asking for discussion. Read the faq; SO is not for discussion.

Comment: also, use oauth. it's secure.

Comment: @Hiroto Sorry about that re: discussion, in any case I'll take a valid answer if one comes up and aware the bounty.  oauth states `OAuth provides a method for users to grant third-party access to their resources without sharing their passwords. It also provides a way to grant limited access (in scope, duration, etc.).` For the situation described (i.e. payment processing), the server requires unlimited access to these APIs at all times for various reasons.  I don't see how this would improve things - the password being shared isn't necessarily the issue.

Comment: Just to add as well, the service I'll be using doesn't support oAth =), as many sites don't just yet.

Answer (score 8):

Based on what I can see in the question, answers, and comments; I would suggest taking advantage of OpenSSL.  This is assuming that your site needs access to this information periodically (meaning it can be scheduled). As you stated:

> The server would need this information to send payments for all sorts of situations. It does not require the "owner" of said keys to log in, in fact the owner might never care to see them ever again once they provide them the first time.

It is from this comment, and the assumption that accessing the data you want to store can be put within a cron job. It is further assumed that you have SSL (https) on your server as you will be dealing with confidential user information, and have the `OpenSSL` and `mcrypt` modules available.. Also, what follows will be rather generic as to 'how' it can be achieved, but not really the details of doing it per your situation. It should also be noted that this 'how-to' is general, and you should do more research before implementing it. That being said, let's get started.

First, let's talk about what OpenSSL provides.  OpenSSL gives us a [Public-Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key): the ability to encrypt data using a public key (which, if compromised, won't compromise the security of the data encrypted with it.) Secondly, it provides a way to access that information with a 'Private Key. As we don't care about creating a certificate (we only need encryption keys), those may be obtained with a simple function (which you'll only use once.):

```
function makeKeyPair()
{
    //Define variables that will be used, set to ''
    $private = '';
    $public = '';
    //Generate the resource for the keys
    $resource = openssl_pkey_new();

    //get the private key
    openssl_pkey_export($resource, $private);

    //get the public key
    $public = openssl_pkey_get_details($resource);
    $public = $public["key"];
    $ret = array('privateKey' => $private, 'publicKey' => $public);
    return $ret;
}
```

Now, you have a *Public* and *Private* key.  Guard the private key, keep it off your server, and keep it out of the database.  Store it on another server, a computer that can run cron jobs, etc.  Just nowhere near the public eye unless you can require an admin to be present every time you require a payment to be processed and encrypt the private key with AES encryption or something similar. The public key, however, will be hard-coded in to your application, and will be used every time a user enters their information to be stored.

Next, you need to determine how you plan to verify the decrypted data (so you don't start posting to payment APIs with invalid requests.)  I am going to assume there are multiple fields that need to be stored, and as we only want to encrypt once, it will be in a PHP array that can be [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)'d. Depending on how much data needs to be stored, we'll either be able to encrypt it directly, or generate a password to encrypt with the public key, and use that random password to encrypt that data itself. I am going to go this route in the explanation.  To go this route, we will use AES encryption, and need to have an encrypt and decrypt function handy - as well as a way to randomly generate a decent one-time pad for the data.  I'll provide the password generator that I use, though I ported it from code I wrote a while back, it will serve the purpose, or you can write a better one. ^^

```
public function generatePassword() {
    //create a random password here
    $chars = array( 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J',  'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T',  'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 'x', 'X', 'y', 'Y', 'z', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '?', '<', '>', '.', ',', ';', '-', '@', '!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')');

    $max_chars = count($chars) - 1;
    srand( (double) microtime()*1000000);

    $rand_str = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
    {
            $rand_str .= $chars[rand(0, $max_chars)];
    }
    return $rand_str;

}
```

This particular function will generate 30 digits, which provides decent entropy - but you can modify it for your needs.  Next, the function to do AES encryption:

```
/**
 * Encrypt AES
 *
 * Will Encrypt data with a password in AES compliant encryption.  It
 * adds built in verification of the data so that the {@link this::decryptAES}
 * can verify that the decrypted data is correct.
 *
 * @param String $data This can either be string or binary input from a file
 * @param String $pass The Password to use while encrypting the data
 * @return String The encrypted data in concatenated base64 form.
 */
public function encryptAES($data, $pass) {
    //First, let's change the pass into a 256bit key value so we get 256bit encryption
    $pass = hash('SHA256', $pass, true);
    //Randomness is good since the Initialization Vector(IV) will need it
    srand();
    //Create the IV (CBC mode is the most secure we get)
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    //Create a base64 version of the IV and remove the padding
    $base64IV = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=');
    //Create our integrity check hash
    $dataHash = md5($data);
    //Encrypt the data with AES 128 bit (include the hash at the end of the data for the integrity check later)
    $rawEnc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $pass, $data . $dataHash, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    //Transfer the encrypted data from binary form using base64
    $baseEnc = base64_encode($rawEnc);
    //attach the IV to the front of the encrypted data (concatenated IV)
    $ret = $base64IV . $baseEnc;
    return $ret;
}
```

(I wrote these function originally to be part of a class, and suggest you implement them in to a class of your own.)  Also, use of this function is fine with a one-time pad that is created, however, if used with a user-specific password for a different application, you definitely need some salt in there to add to the password.  Next, to decrypt and verify the decrypted data is correct:

```
/**
 * Decrypt AES
 *
 * Decrypts data previously encrypted WITH THIS CLASS, and checks the
 * integrity of that data before returning it to the programmer.
 *
 * @param String $data The encrypted data we will work with
 * @param String $pass The password used for decryption
 * @return String|Boolean False if the integrity check doesn't pass, or the raw decrypted data.
 */
public function decryptAES($data, $pass){
    //We used a 256bit key to encrypt, recreate the key now
    $pass = hash('SHA256', $this->salt . $pass, true);
    //We should have a concatenated data, IV in the front - get it now
    //NOTE the IV base64 should ALWAYS be 22 characters in length.
    $base64IV = substr($data, 0, 22) .'=='; //add padding in case PHP changes at some point to require it
    //change the IV back to binary form
    $iv = base64_decode($base64IV);
    //Remove the IV from the data
    $data = substr($data, 22);
    //now convert the data back to binary form
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    //Now we can decrypt the data
    $decData = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $pass, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    //Now we trim off the padding at the end that php added
    $decData = rtrim($decData, "\0");
    //Get the md5 hash we stored at the end
    $dataHash = substr($decData, -32);
    //Remove the hash from the data
    $decData = substr($decData, 0, -32);
    //Integrity check, return false if it doesn't pass
    if($dataHash != md5($decData)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        //Passed the integrity check, give use their data
        return $decData;
    }
}
```

Look at both of the functions, read the comments, etc.  Figure out what they do and how they work so you don't implement them incorrectly.  Now, to encrypting the user-data.  We'll encrypt it with the public key, and the following functions assume that every function so far (and to come) is in the same class.  I'll provide both the OpenSSL encrypt/decrypt functions at once as we'll need the second later.

```
/**
 * Public Encryption
 *
 * Will encrypt data based on the public key
 *
 * @param String $data The data to encrypt
 * @param String $publicKey The public key to use
 * @return String The Encrypted data in base64 coding
 */
public function publicEncrypt($data, $publicKey) {
    //Set up the variable to get the encrypted data
    $encData = '';
    openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encData, $publicKey);
    //base64 code the encrypted data
    $encData = base64_encode($encData);
    //return it
    return $encData;
}

/**
 * Private Decryption
 *
 * Decrypt data that was encrypted with the assigned private
 * key's public key match. (You can't decrypt something with
 * a private key if it doesn't match the public key used.)
 *
 * @param String $data The data to decrypt (in base64 format)
 * @param String $privateKey The private key to decrypt with.
 * @return String The raw decoded data
 */
public function privateDecrypt($data, $privateKey) {
    //Set up the variable to catch the decoded date
    $decData = '';
    //Remove the base64 encoding on the inputted data
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    //decrypt it
    openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decData, $privateKey);
    //return the decrypted data
    return $decData;
}
```

The `$data` in these is always going to be the one-time pad, not the user information.  Next, the functions to combine both the Public Key Encryption and AES of the one-time pad for encryption and decryption.

```
/**
 * Secure Send
 *
 * OpenSSL and 'public-key' schemes are good for sending
 * encrypted messages to someone that can then use their
 * private key to decrypt it.  However, for large amounts
 * of data, this method is incredibly slow (and limited).
 * This function will take the public key to encrypt the data
 * to, and using that key will encrypt a one-time-use randomly
 * generated password.  That one-time password will be
 * used to encrypt the data that is provided.  So the data
 * will be encrypted with a one-time password that only
 * the owner of the private key will be able to uncover.
 * This method will return a base64encoded serialized array
 * so that it can easily be stored, and all parts are there
 * without modification for the receive function
 *
 * @param String $data The data to encrypt
 * @param String $publicKey The public key to use
 * @return String serialized array of 'password' and 'data'
 */
public function secureSend($data, $publicKey)
{
    //First, we'll create a 30digit random password
    $pass = $this->generatePassword();
    //Now, we will encrypt in AES the data
    $encData = $this->encryptAES($data, $pass);
    //Now we will encrypt the password with the public key
    $pass = $this->publicEncrypt($pass, $publicKey);
    //set up the return array
    $ret = array('password' => $pass, 'data' => $encData);
    //serialize the array and then base64 encode it
    $ret = serialize($ret);
    $ret = base64_encode($ret);
    //send it on its way
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Secure Receive
 *
 * This is the complement of {@link this::secureSend}.
 * Pass the data that was returned from secureSend, and it
 * will dismantle it, and then decrypt it based on the
 * private key provided.
 *
 * @param String $data the base64 serialized array
 * @param String $privateKey The private key to use
 * @return String the decoded data.
 */
public function secureReceive($data, $privateKey) {
    //Let's decode the base64 data
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    //Now let's put it into array format
    $data = unserialize($data);
    //assign variables for the different parts
    $pass = $data['password'];
    $data = $data['data'];
    //Now we'll get the AES password by decrypting via OpenSSL
    $pass = $this->privateDecrypt($pass, $privateKey);
    //and now decrypt the data with the password we found
    $data = $this->decryptAES($data, $pass);
    //return the data
    return $data;
}
```

I left the comments intact to help understanding of these functions.  Now is where we get down to the fun part, actually working with the users data.  The `$data` in the `send` method is the user-data in a serialized array.  Remember for the send method that the `$publicKey` is hard-coded, you can store as a variable in your class and access it that way for less variables to pass to it, or have it inputted from elsewhere to send to the method every time.  Example usage to encrypt the data:

```
$myCrypt = new encryptClass();
$userData = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'password' => $_POST['pass'],
    'api' => $_POST['api_key']
);
$publicKey = "the public key from earlier";
$encData = $myCrypt->secureSend(serialize($userData), $publicKey));
//Now store the $encData in the DB with a way to associate with the user
//it is base64 encoded, so it is safe for DB input.
```

Now, that's the easy part, the next part is being able to use that data.  For that, you'll need a page on your server that accepts `$_POST['privKey']` and will then loop through the users, etc in the fashion that is needed for your site, grabbing the `$encData`.  Sample usage to decrypt from this:

```
$myCrypt = new encryptClass();
$encData = "pulled from DB";
$privKey = $_POST['privKey'];
$data = unserialize($myCrypt->secureReceive($encData, $privKey));
//$data will now contain the original array of data, or false if
//it failed to decrypt it.  Now do what you need with it.
```

Next, the specific theory of use to access that secure page with the private key.  On a separate server, you'll have a cron job that runs a php script specifically not in `public_html` containing the private key, then use [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post the private key to your page that is looking for it. **(Make sure you are calling an address that begins with *https*)**

I hope that helps answer how it is possible to store the user information securely within your application that won't be compromised by accessing either your code or your database.

Comment: Awarding yo the bounty. It's the most complete and best answer out of what we have here.  Thanks Jon.

Comment: Thank you!  You are welcome ^^  Though, from that wording, I assume not quite what you were looking for?

Comment: Well I think I realize that there might not be a way to do exactly what I'm speaking about very securely without a 3rd party service (which both parties agree to use), or something like you describe here is all.

Comment: I would agree with that statement.  With storing that kind of information, if on your own servers especially, it would be your responsibility to ensure that if the code or database is compromised, the information therein is not. However, the storage of payment information could be handled easier if products being purchased weren't required to have the storage of sensitive information. If you contact me (link in profile), I would be more than happy to discuss this more on other options you can use that may help your particular situation if I know what that situation is. ^^

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I can summarize the problem - and then my answer to what I understand the problem.

You would like to have users login to your application, and then store 3rd party credentials.  (It doesn't matter what those credentials are...)  For security, you'd like there not to be an easy way to decrypt those credentials in the case of a hacker gaining access to the database.

Here is what I suggest.

1. Create an authentication system for the user to log in to your application.  The user MUST login each time they visit the site.  When storing access to all of these other credentials, a "remember me" is just a horrible idea.  Authentication is created by combining and hashing username, password, and a salt.  This way, none of that information is stored in the db.
2. A hashed version of the username / password combination is stored in the session.  This becomes the MASTER KEY.
3. 3rd party information is entered.  This information is encrypted using the MASTER KEY hash.

So this means...

If a user doesn't know their password, they are out of luck.  However, it would be a very difficult situation for a hacker to get the information.  They would need to understand the hashing of the username, password, salt, to break authentication, then have that hashed version of hte username/password for the master key, and then use that to decyrpt the data.

It is possible to still be hacked, but very hard - unprobable.  I would also say this gives you relative deniability because, according to this method, you never know the information on the server, as it is encrypted before it is stored.  This method is similar to how I assume services like OnePassword work.

Comment: Not exactly.  The intent here is for the server to use these credentials programmatically.  For example, it could be a payment API username/password/API keys.  The server would need this information to send payments for all sorts of situations.  It does not require the "owner" of said keys to log in, in fact the owner might never care to see them ever again once they provide them the first time.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the clarification.  Well, while I can't say "that can't be done better than others have suggested," it's beyond what I can offer.  I can't imagine a scenario where the encryption key is so disconnected that a compromised server AND db still render the data unusable.  This, of course, is the reason why many services are now using OAuth.  I hate to be that guy that says "use this tool instead!!" but perhaps if security is that paramount, you may consider only supporting services that provide hashed key access.

Comment: @Shackrock Would the information that the user enters be scheduled to be used? (ie would your situation allow for all payments that need to be made throughout the day to be made at once, or incremental?) Or as a result of their direct interactions with the site?

Comment: @jon They would be based on other user input.  I.e. a different user makes a payment for a product, and the API keys/username/password for the person whose product is being bought is accessed immediately and the payment is sent.

Comment: @Shackrock There won't be a clean way to do it then within the same server, though you can modify my answer somewhat and put the payment in a que (use the Public Key encryption on CC info) and run the cron every minute or so to check for new payments so it would almost be seemless, but would require the purchasing user wait until the cron processes the payment, and then updates the DB so if the user checks back and sees that the payment went through and can then (get the product, make the download, etc) from there.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible solutions if you think out of the box... and can act out of the box, which isn't necessarily your case, but I'm going to suggest them anyways.

1. Obtain accounts with limited permissions from the 3rd party site. In your payment gateway example, an account that allows you to authorize and settle payments, but not to call the TransferToBankAccount($accountNumber) API.

   - Similarly, ask the provider to put in restrictions. $accountNumber has to be one of several you've provided or maybe just has to be in the same country as you're located in*.
2. Some secure systems rely on a hardware token to provide authentication. (I'm mostly thinking of key-creation and signing dongles.) I'm not sure exactly how this would work in your situation. Assume you've got a dongle that you request the authentication from and it'll only reply under certain circumstances. This is difficult if all it can do is to give (or not give) a username / password. (Vs say, signing a request, where it can examine the request parameters). You could possibly do this with a SSL client certificate, where the request to the 3rd party requires the username / pass / and client signature -- if your 3rd party would accept such a thing.
3. A combination of #1 and #2. Set up another server to act as a go-between. This server would implement basic business logic that I suggested your 3rd party could do in #1. It exposes an API and checks to make sure that the request is "valid" (payments can be settled, but only outgoing transfers to your account #, etc) before grabbing the auth details and making the request directly. The API can include SetAuthDetails, but not GetAuthDetails. The benefit here is that it's one more thing for the attacker to compromise.
   And, the simpler the server the easier it is to harden. (No need to run SMTP, FTP, and whatever potentially buggy PHP stack your main server has.... just a few PHP scripts, port 443, SSH, and a, e.g., sqlite instance. Keeping the HTTPD and PHP up to date should be easier because there's less concern about compatibility issues.)
4. Assume you will get compromised and monitor / audit for the potential effects. Have another server somewhere that (yes) has the auth details to log in and check the auth logs (or, ideally, read-only permission). Have it check every minute and check for unauthorized logins and / or transactions and do something drastic (maybe change the password to something random and page you).

*Whether we're actually talking about a payment gateway or not, any 3rd party that you're this concerned about being hacked over should also be concerned about their own security, including if you (or other clients) get hacked. They're also liable to one extent or another, so they should be willing to put in safeguards.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a random salt based on X criteria that you can predict but that a hacker couldn't then depending on how you write the code it still may not be apparent what is what even if the hacker gains access to everything.

For example, you use the current time and date plus the users IP address as a salt. You then store those values along with the hash in he database. You obfuscate the function used to create the hash and it might not be so obvious what the salt was. Of course any determined hacker can break that eventually but it buys you time and some additional level of protection.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is the same idea as storing some kind of "encryption password" hard-coded in the PHP.  Like you said, the hacker could figure out my method of generating this and in the end it's just like a hard-coded PHP password, but yes it does buy some time.

Comment: If the security of this is mission critical, I'd rent a second server who's sole job was to store the database. That way if he hacker breaks into your code they still don't have the database info and vice versa.

Comment: @aguyfromhere:  If your app server can access the database, and it gets hacked, then how do you figure the hacker wouldn't be able to access the database?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Users are not all very tech savvy but a user, asked to provide credentials for a third party's site, should run away from your site as quick as he can. This is simply a bad idea. The question about storing plaintext passwords definitely applies here, too. Don't do it.

You are not providing much context about the third parties in question nor about your relation with them. But you should talk with them about if they are willing to make some changes to support your use case. Them implementing oauth would be a good solution.

If you want to look around for alternatives, look up [federated identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity)

Comment: The context is that of a payment processor and a merchant.  For example: Site has many merchants.  User can buy from any of the merchants on the site.  Site needs credentials/API keys for every merchant in order to send money to the right place.

Comment: There's tons of rules, checks, audits and legalese concerning the security of handling payment information. You don't get to decide what's secure enough and what's not. The banks and credit card companies write the rules.

Comment: this is not about PCI standards, which can be met by simply storing these credentials in plaintext in a DB.  PCI is about cardholder security.  The question is about best practices for storing this API/merchant credential-type information (so that we don't have to store it plaintext in the DB).