# How to store encrypted password into LDAP attribute？

Tags: encryption, ldap, schema, openldap

```
attributetype (1.3.6.1.4.1.XXX.2 NAME 'Password'
    DESC 'user password'
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
    SUP name
    SINGLE-VALUE)
```

I wrote a ldap schema to define an objectClass,before I added an encrypted password to this objectClass with above attribute,it ran without any problem.However,when encrypted password was added in this attribute,something wrong accured:`ldap add failed:Invalid syntax`

**Is** `SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15` do not support encrypted password? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you actually mean *encrypted* (i.e. reversible, to obtain the original password) or do you mean *hashed*, i.e comparable for authentication, but not reversible to reveal the original?

Comment: It's a reversible encrypted password(3des  algorithm)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie/2287672#2287672) for why you should definitely not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your understanding of an "encrypted" password is, but if it means that you're trying to add binary data to this attribute, then the `SYNTAX` definition is not compatible.

`1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15` is a *Directory String* according to [RFC 2252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2252):

> A string in this syntax is encoded in the UTF-8 form of ISO 10646 (a
> superset of Unicode).  Servers and clients MUST be prepared to
> receive encodings of arbitrary Unicode characters, including
> characters not presently assigned to any character set.

This does not support arbitrary binary data.

Comment: The password I mentioned above is encrypted by 3des algorithm（pkcs5）.Is  there any syntax to support it?