# How can I encrypt password on client side and decrypt it on server side?

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt my password after created user and persist it inside the DB. I write password to "password field" and press "Save button". Then I use [this library](http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html)

For encryption

```
        BasicPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
        String encryptedPasword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(myPasword);
        user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setUserRole(role);
        user.setFistname(firstname);
        user.setLastname(lastname);
        user.setGroupId(group);
        user.setBssLogin(login);
        user.setBssPassword(encryptedPasword);
        dao.addCrmUser(user);
```

After that, I have a new encrypted password inside my DB.

On the server side, I get the user and try to decrypt the password

```
String login = user.getLogin();
String password = user.getPassword();
String dencryptPassword = encryptor.**NOT_METHOD_FOR_IT**(password);
```

I need the original password, which is set inside another system.
How can I do this with my current library ?

I fount [this](https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption) and another libraries in Github that use some `key` but I do not know what is better and/or faster.

Comment: See [tag:password-encryption] for why you should not do this, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie/2287672#2287672) for ethical reasons you can advance to the client.

Comment: My system use another system. How can I login to another system if i do not know user password?

Answer (score -1):

You do not decrypt the password from the database to verify it.

You *encrypt* the password received from the user when trying to login, and compare that encrypted value with the value in the database.  Good password encryption is really a hash function, which is not reversible, for security.

Comment: I compare this password with the password is not in the database. There is another system, it has its own database, and the password is there in its original form

Comment: I understand that this is a bad decision, but the customer requires. I store the login and password from another system in your user

Comment: That is extremely bad design.  Passwords should never be stored in plaintext, only the hashes should be stored.

Comment: so I want to encrypt the password when it is added to web forms into their database and on the server to decrypt to send to another system

Comment: But you are asking how to decrypt the stored password.  It can't be both ways.  Either the password is stored hashed, in which case you hash the login password and compare, or it is coming in unhashed, in which case there is no problem.

Comment: Then you cannot use a one-way hash, and you WILL have to compromise security.  Explain to your employer that what they are doing violates all basic security principles.

Comment: maybe I can encrypt with any key, and decrypted on the server with the same key? and the key to register directly in the code, strictly? or advise a solution to do this?

Comment: The key will have to be visible on the client == no security

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain. Head understands but insists to store the password on the target system at the database

Comment: client and server - internal product of the company.

Comment: by the way the password is stored is not the server and client))))) the client has сonnect database)))) architecture is such here)))

Answer (score -1):

The `BasicPasswordEncryptor()` in **jasypt** does despite it's name, not encrypt the password, but hashes the password using a one-way-hash (A big tell, is that the method don't require an encryption key).

You can't get the password back after this process, and the password is verified using the `checkPassword(String plainPassword, String encryptedPassword)` methode.

If you really need to be able to decrypt the password, you need to use another way to do **real** encryption when encrypting it. This raises the need for handling of encryption keys, which might introduce just as many problems than it sorts (where to store them etc.)