# Export Passwords from ldap

Tags: encryption, passwords, ldap, ldif

I have a list of user accounts with passwords in different formats (Binary 11, Binary 3, Binary 33). When I export as ldif, it has all encrypted passwords. I want all passwords as plain text. (As I can see in ldap). Can I have plain passwords in exported file?

Answer (score 0):

I doub it. When you export as LDIF, it has all *hashed* passwords. Not encrypted. You can't decrypt a hash. You can't get the plaintext. You don't *want* the plaintext. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie/2287672#2287672) for why not.

Review your requirement.

Comment: They aren't hashed, they are encrypted Base 64. I can even decrypt them. I can get plain password through ldap too. But in export, they are encrypted.
I understand why should not I want plain text. But this is it.