# MySQL / Store MySQL Credentials

Tags: database, security, credentials, mysql

How can I store credentials for other MySQL servers in a MySQL database securely?

I'm working on a project which requires that I connect to other's MySQL servers, but I don't know how to securely store the username and password. I would need to get them in plaintext somehow since I will need to connect using them later, but that wouldn't be safe since an attacker could easily get all the credentials.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I ethically approach user password storage for later plaintext retrieval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie)

Comment: This is a common problem. The question is, what level of security you need to achieve and what your budget is for the above. If you want a high level of security, then you are not really going to find a free solution.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks! I think I will make it generate the password, and the end user will create a new MySQL user set the password to what it requests with as few permissions as possible.

Comment: Your attacker comments are a bit nebulous. Look into TLS/SSL and PKI

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer for a similar question: [What's a secure alternative to using a MySQL password on the command line?](https://serverfault.com/questions/476228/whats-a-secure-alternative-to-using-a-mysql-password-on-the-command-line/504841#504841)

Basically MySQL 5.6 introduces a new method to solve this problem.