# Storing a password safely but being accessible in plaintext

Tags: password-protection

We have an application server, which needs to access passwords to login to other services etc. In our current implementation the passwords are saved in a plaintext file, which obviously isn't the best solution. 
What are "the got to" approaches in these scenarios? I'm fairly new to this so open to suggestions.

What I was thinking of was somehow encrypting the file itself, so it can't be opened normally but can be read by a c# programm - this level of security would suffice - but I wouldn't know how to achieve this.

Side info: 
I don't need any reset features and aren't storing user passwords or anything. Just "constant" passwords for services to login to.

**Edit**: We have a sql database and are managing it with SQL management studio

What I found: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/store-passwords-using-reversible-encryption
As i understand it, this is a windows feature which encrypts and stores passwords but makes them decryptable also. Any experience with this?

Related questions but no real answers there:
[How should I ethically approach user password storage for later plaintext retrieval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retrie)

Comment: Is switching to SQL database out of the question here?

Comment: Ah - sorry i have to add this to the question: We do have a database and are managing it with sql management studio

Comment: You should probably look into password hashing. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @annoyingnoob yeah but isn't the point of hashing that it is irreversible? In my case i would like to extract the password as plaintext. Sure i could encrypt it with a certain algo and decrypt it again in my application and probably no one will guess what i encrypted it with, but still.