# How to de-hash in php?

Tags: php, hash

Is there any function in php which allows me to de-hashing a string?

For example:

```
$hashedInfo = hash('md5', 'Hello World!');
```

I want to do the inverse thing, something like:

```
$deashedInfo = dehash('md5', $hashedInfo);
```

Thank you!

Comment: md5 is one way hash i think, and NO but you can use any other crypto functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP dehashing the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615408/php-dehashing-the-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, because md5 function is not bijective. 2 different inputs can result in same hash value.

Comment: However, since MD5 is widely used, the value can be reverse-engineered in seconds via Rainbow Table. Google it. Keep in mind that MD5 is not safe.

Comment: @Raptor If I have a document that's 5 MB in size, that Rainbow Table de-hashing scheme is not going to reverse engineer it in any short amount of time. Rainbow Table is fine for cracking relatively short strings like passwords, but it's not a generalized "create text from hash" function.