# Forgot password asp.net using database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to do a link with a forgot password. I did the part where I send the message to the email but I don't really get how to take the password from SQL database and send it on email.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AMPRConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from logare where email='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*******", "*****");

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("******");
        mailMessage.Subject = ("Password recoverd");
        mailMessage.Body = "Dear " + TextBox1.Text + ", Your Password is  "+ ? ;
        client.Send(mailMessage);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Email has been sent succesfully !');", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Could not send email" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I don't really get how to take the password from SQL database and send it on email"* - You don't.  User passwords should be obscured behind a 1-way hashing algorithm and should *never* be retrievable in their original form.  You can let the user *change* their password, but you should never be able to *show* the user their current password.

Comment: On top of that, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683 before you proceed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018180/best-practice-for-resetting-forgotten-user-passwords/16018373#16018373

Answer (score 0):

```
  --------------------aspx page code----------------------
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlForgot" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnGet">
                <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
                    id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                    &times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">
                                    Forgot Password ?</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg1" runat="server" Style="color: red; font-weight: 400;"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                <p>
                                    Enter your E-Mail ID below to reset your password.</p>
                                <asp:Label ID="passlabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMailorMobile" runat="server" MaxLength="100" placeholder="E-Mail ID"
                                    autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" Style="margin-bottom: 0" autofocus required></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" OnClick="btnForgot_Click" Text="Get Password"
                                    class="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="return validate();" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPassword" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            ----------------------aspx.cs code----------------------
             protected void btnForgot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //String pass = "select AppMstPassword from AppMst where AppMstEMailId like'" + txtMailorMobile.Text + "'";
            string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            DataWrapper objdatawrapper = new DataWrapper(str, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            objdatawrapper.AddParameter("@email", txtMailorMobile.Text, SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter sp = (SqlParameter)objdatawrapper.AddParameter("@password", null, SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output, 200);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = objdatawrapper.ExecuteDataSet("forgetpassword");
            if (sp.Value.ToString() !="" || sp.Value.ToString()==null)
            {
                passlabel.Text = sp.Value.ToString();
                passlabel.Visible = false;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Password has been sent to your mail id')", true);

            }
            else
            {
                passlabel.Text = "You are not a registered member";
                passlabel.Visible = false;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('You are not a registered member')", true);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string mg = ex.ToString();
        }



        string MailMsg = "";





        MailMsg += "<table style='background:white;width:544px;font-size: 14.0px;border: 2.0px solid #e8e8e8;margin-left: 180px;'>";
        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td style='background-color:#ffffff;' align='center'> </td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr align='center' style='background: #1b88ce;padding: 10px 5px;'>";
        MailMsg += "<td><h2 align='center' style='text-align: center;color: #ffffff;font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;margin:0;'>Reset Password </h2></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td>Hi Sir/Mam, </td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td>You recently requested a password reset.your password is '"+passlabel.Text+"'</td>";
//        MailMsg += passlabel.Text;
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td>The link will expire in 24 Hours.If you did not make this request, you may simply ignore this email. </td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td>Thank You,<br/> Our Company Name</td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;'></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><p> Any Message type here</p></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";



        MailMsg += "<tr>";
        MailMsg += "<td><br/><br/></td>";
        MailMsg += "</tr>";

        MailMsg += "</table>";
       MailMsg = MailMsg + "<p style='padding:10px; line-height:8px; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>Proud Leagal Team </p></div>";
        Mail.SendMailMessage("xyz@gmail.com", "" + txtMailorMobile.Text + "", "!!! XYZ !!! Forgot Password", "" + MailMsg.ToString() + "");

        reset();
    }


    -----------------Add this App Code File---------------

    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace businesslayer
{
    public class SMS
    {
        public SMS()
        {
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        }
        public static String sendsms(string No, string Msg)
        {
            String status="";
            try
            {
                String req;
                req = "http://sms.xyz.com/WebServiceSMS.aspx?User=xyzsms&passwd=1234&mobilenumber=" + No + "&message=" + Msg + "&sid=XYZ&mtype=N";

                HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(req);
                HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
                string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                respStreamReader.Close();
                myResp.Close();
                status = responseString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status = "URL is not responding at the moment." + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```